# Microsoft Word switches fonts when I switch input language

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, language, microsoft-word-2016, international

I am using Microsoft Word 2016 from my Office 365 subscription with the default template for new documents. When I type in English characters, they are put into the document using the correct default font Calibri. However, when I switch my input language to Russian or Ukrainian to type in words from my native languages, MS Word changes the font automatically to Times New Roman. Is there a way to tell Word not to do that and use the same font for my native languages?

---

Extra info that may help.

When I open the properties of the Normal style, I see this:

[image]

As you can see, the Normal style uses two fonts, and one of them is marked as "(Intl)". As I understand, this is the font used for international characters - which is my case. However, I could not find how to change this font to Calibri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

microsoft.com [helped me](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_365hp/microsoft-word-2016-switches-fonts-when-i-switch/aca44ca8-73d7-44be-b2c4-008b08e413bf) to solve the problem. They pointed to this solution:

[Word changes font on some language specific characters while writing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/word-changes-font-on-some-language-specific/6328a0ea-81cd-4041-b254-34ce03c24604)

In a nutshell, the problem was in the broken or wrong Normal.dotm default document file. To resolve the issue, we need to delete this file and launch MS Word to recreate a correct version of Normal.dotm.

Comment: This is the nuclear solution. Instead of solving the specific problem, it is resetting all of the settings.